# Vue: Unit Test dynamic compoment

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, testing, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I have a component where a fieldgroup ( label, input and errors ) is added. The input element is imported dynamically, according to the prop ( `settings.input.component` ) it receives from the parent component.

And I wanted to test this component, in order to understand if the behavior is correct and performs the intended.

The problem is that I am not able to simulate the import of the input component and as such when I look for the element it does not exist.

Do you have any suggestions?

## component - import dynamic

```
<template>
    <div class="field position--relative">
        <label>
          ....
        </label>
            <component
                :is="inputComponent"
                ...
            />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        settings: Object
    },
    data () {
        return {
            inputComponent: null,
        };
    },
    ...
    watch: {
        'settings.input.component': {
            immediate: true,
            deep: false,
            async handler ( newComponent ) {
                // get input component
                this.inputComponent = () => import(
                    /* webpackChunkName: '[request]' */
                    `@/components/dynamic/inputs/${newComponent}`
                ).then( chunk => chunk.default || chunk );
            }
        },

    }
};
</script>
```

## Test

```
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate';
import { resetState } from '../helpers/index';
import store from '@/store/';
import BaseField from '@/components/bundles/fields/BaseField';

const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use( Vuex );
localVue.use( Vuelidate );

describe( 'components', () => {
    // antes de cada teste, é feito
    // o reset a store
    beforeEach( resetState );
    describe( 'fields', () => {
        it( 'add field to store', () => {
            // define settings of component
            const wrapper = shallowMount( BaseField, {
                propsData: {
                    settings: {
                        input: {
                            component: 'InputBasic'
                        },
                    }
                },
            });

            // find input
            const input = wrapper.find( 'input' );

            console.log( input );
            console.log( wrapper.html() );
        });
    });
});
```

## result

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to solve the problem. I needed to flush the promises.

Here is an example of the test working.

```
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate';
import VueCompositionAPI from '@vue/composition-api';
import BaseField from '@/components/bundles/fields/BaseField';
import { resetState } from '../helpers/index';

const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use( Vuex );
localVue.use( Vuelidate );
localVue.use( VueCompositionAPI );

function flushPromises () {
    return new Promise( resolve => setImmediate( resolve ) );
}

describe( 'components', () => {
    beforeEach( resetState );
    describe( 'fields', () => {
        it( 'add', async () => {
            const wrapper = shallowMount( BaseField, {
                propsData: {
                       ...
                    }
                },
                localVue
            });

            await flushPromises();

            const input = wrapper.find( '.field__input' );

            await input.setValue( 'my@mail.com' );
            input.trigger( 'blur' );

            expect( input.element.value ).toBe( 'my@mail.com' );

            expect( wrapper.vm.$data.value ).toBe( 'my@mail.com' );
        });
    });
});
```

Flush promises:

```
function flushPromises () {
    return new Promise( resolve => setImmediate( resolve ) );
}
```