# Trouble getting wrapper for dynamic child component

Tags: vuejs2, vue-test-utils

I'm trying to write a unit test for a VueJS 2 component that has a dynamic component that changes as the state changes.

```
<template>
    <div>
<component ref="dynamicComponent" id="dynamicComponent" :is="someDynamicType" @custom-event="handleCustomEvent">
</component>
    </div>
</template>
```

What i'm trying to test is that the parent component is handling the custom-event from the child dynamic component correctly.  However, the problem I'm running into is that I cannot seem to get a reference to the child dynamic component.

I've tried

```
await wrapper.findComponent('#dynamicComponent').vm.$emit("custom-event", {});
```

and

```
await wrapper.find({ref: 'dynamicComponent'}).vm.$emit("custom-event", {});
```

and I also tried using the known type of the dynamic component

```
await wrapper.findComponent(KnownSubType).vm.$emit("custom-event", {});
```

but in each case, I get the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$emit')
```

Is there another way to obtain the component so that I can emit the custom event or is there another way to trigger the event to test my parent component?

Comment: Hey Man. I'm struggling with the same issue. Have you found a solution maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem writing tests using dynamic components. To ensure that the child component was loaded before manipulating it in my tests I had to flush promises. This can be either written manually like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65665052/11015616

or

the `flush-promises` npm library can be used.

```
const wrapper = mount(SomeComponent, {options});
await flushPromises();
// manipulate child component
```

Comment: also the vue/test-utils exports it's own flushPromises function https://test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#flushPromises